# Connecting to internet using two routers

Tags: router, windows-server-2016

I have two routers.

The main one with the internet access is a SIM card router. Meaning it gets internet from 4G. It has options for DHCP but only on WLAN. Also the DHCP is rudimentary, it only has options for range and no DHCP table for permanent IP. It has one WAN/LAN port on the back.

The second router is a TP-Link ER6020. This is a much more advanced router meant to handle DHCP requests so that my ADDS can have a permanent IP address and all computers on that network can join the domain and that works.

I am using Windows Server 2016 for AD.

My problem is I want to be able to access the internet, but the main router with internet is the only option I have for internet access. This is a problem here in Ghana, Africa. The school I am working for only has access to such a device because the companies refuse to give mainline infrastructure in our area because lines get 
cut and stolen.

Question: Is there a way to setup the two routers to work together so that the computers can access the domain and the internet?

Comment: Would it work if I disable DHCP on both routers, setup DHCP on Windows Server, and have access to internet?

Comment: What is doing NAT, the TP Link? If so, try and set the 4G router to transparent bridging (if it has the feature). If the 4G router can't be bridged, you can double-NAT. Not ideal, but it should still work. Either way I would have Windows Server running DHCP, yes.

Comment: After trying to setup DHCP on Windows Server, I realize that the 4G router does not connect to 4G if I disable WLAN DHCP. It only has DHCP on WLAN therefore since the only port in the back is WAN/LAN port it decided to get internet access from the port rather than 4G. I guess I will have to look for other options when trying to gain internet access.

Comment: Ok, so the 4G modem cannot be bridged, but you should be able to set it up like so:  
WAN IP on 4G router via DHCP from ISP, NAT'd to private IP > Just use a switch here, not the TP-Link router > DHCP done on Windows Server.   
That setup should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like my 4G router is too rudimentary for the things I need it for. I will have to look for different options when it comes to getting internet access for the lab.

Comment: Your 4G device is modem/router combo...or just a modem?